# Convert a text to lowercase but keep uppercase for first letter in word (with R, if possible in tm package)

Tags: string, r, lowercase, tm

Is there an R function for changing a text to lowercase, but for the first letter of each word, i.e. change?

```
"You live NEAR Chicago"
```

to

```
"You live Near Chicago"
```

The point is to benefit from a quite efficient implementation, if possible.

Could this be integrated to the [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) R package (or is already available there), so that it could be applied to a corpus directly?

(the goal is to built a simple location detector in text, crossing with geonames).

Comment: To check: You want "live" to stay as "live" rather than become "Live"?

Comment: Thx. I want "live" to stay "live". I can write such a function, but I was expecting that it existed, since it does a tolower, but keeping the capital letters required by names of places people and institutions (ie named entities), as well as the first letter in each sentence.

Comment: So for "The CIA is tapping my phone" you want "The Cia is tapping my phone"?

Comment: @Jongware : yes, I can do with this CIA and other acronyms. This is for an application with rather specific documents (tenders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're handling the bit where the word(s) (like "near") are next to the geographic location(s), then there are existing code snippets for something like a `ucfirst` bit of functionality. However, you mentioned speed, so here's a comparison between an `Rcpp` implementation and a basic/straight R implementation (both are vectorized):

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

# pure Rcpp/C++ implementation

sourceCpp("
#include <Rcpp.h> 

using namespace Rcpp; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector< std::string > ucfirst( std::vector< std::string > strings ) {

  int len = strings.size();

  for( int i=0; i < len; i++ ) {
    std::transform(strings[i].begin(), strings[i].end(), strings[i].begin(), ::tolower);
    strings[i][0] = toupper( strings[i][0] );
  }

  return strings;

}")

r_ucfirst <- function (str) {
  paste(toupper(substring(str, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(str, 2)), sep = "")
}

print(ucfirst("hello"))
## [1] "Hello"

print(r_ucfirst("hello"))
## [1] "Hello"

mb <- microbenchmark(ucfirst("hello"), r_ucfirst("hello"), times=1000)
print(mb)

## Unit: microseconds
##                expr   min    lq median     uq    max neval
##    ucfirst("hello") 1.925 2.123 2.2765 2.4025 20.844  1000
##  r_ucfirst("hello") 6.199 7.059 7.5285 7.9555 41.473  1000
```

Both should be compatible across-platforms. You can get even faster in C++ with some C-hacks, but 2.27μs for 1,000 conversions isn't exactly bad (neither is 7.5μs for the pure-R version :-)

Having said that, you could try implementing the "pure R" version with the [stringi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/) package, which uses Rcpp/C++/C-backed functions.